# Node.js stream.on('end'... does not make file readable

Tags: node.js, canvas, stream, node-canvas

I try to catch the completion of writing the canvas stream thusly:

```
    var out = fs.createWriteStream(out_fs);
    var stream = canvas.createPNGStream({
        bufsize: 2048
    });
    stream.on('end', function () {
      // can we use out_fs now? why not?
    });
    stream.pipe(out);
```

But when I try to load `out_fs` in sub function

> Error: Image given has not completed loading

at this line:

```
            fs.readFile(out_fs, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    var img = new Canvas.Image; // Create a new Image
                    img.src = data;
                    ctx2.drawImage(img, 0, 50, img.width, img.height); <--
```

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end

But I don't see any other way to continue with the control flow after the stream is written. If I let the entire parent function return, the file then seems readable. I've tried wrapping my child functions in `setImmediate()`, but that only seems to work intermittently.

What is the definitive way to catch the final usable end result of writing the stream?

The node-canvas documentation claims that the `end` event signals the final writing of the file: https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas#canvaspngstream

But this generates the error above if you immediately try to use it.

`finish' does not seem to be implemented at all.

Comment: You'd think that would work, but it never gets called at all.

Comment: `.on('end')` should be enough, I think you should post more code, as there may be a control flow problem (something running before you think, etc).

Comment: @aarosil ok I am not proud of the pyramid of doom - you are probably right. But in essence I am generating one canvas object, and then I generate a second canvas object which is a montage of the first + two external img files. http://pastebin.com/E0J1QTvr

Comment: Couple of things, you can always use `fs.readFileSync()`, to eliminate callbacks (it will block other code execution however).  It seems like some image names are hardcoded you can read those files w/ `sync` at top of script and preserve those results.  Should make it easier for you to debug further, at least

Comment: Can you try replace `stream.on('end', ...)` above, with `out.on('close', ...)` an see what happens?

Comment: @aarosil That worked. I was utterly confused about which stream I needed to piggy back off. Thank you so much! Feel free to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have piped `stream` to `out`, `out` will be `close()`'d automatically on `stream`'s `end` event (this is part of what gets setup automatically when you `.pipe()` a stream).  So, to know when file is finished being written, listen to the `close` event of `out` stream.

You saw intermittent results because the `stream` `end` event is the same event that will be used by `out` writable stream to finalize the file.

Answer (score 1):

I would put this in a comment (but can't):

You need to close your WriteStream called 'out' - use the event aarosil suggests and do `out.close()`

Comment: That might be right - doesn't solve the problem though - it's the `stream` object that is generating the error. I updated the question with more detail.

Comment: I think aarosil has it with the comment below